# GTK3/gtkmm: Drag and drop image from browser

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I have implemented the behavior of dragging pictures from the file manager to Gtk::DrawingArea

```
std::vector<Gtk::TargetEntry> listTargets;
listTargets.push_back(Gtk::TargetEntry("text/uri-list"));
drag_dest_set(listTargets, (Gtk::DEST_DEFAULT_MOTION | Gtk::DEST_DEFAULT_DROP), (Gdk::ACTION_COPY | Gdk::ACTION_MOVE));
signal_drag_data_received().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &CanvasArea::on_dropped_file));
```

What needs to be done to be able to drag and drop an image from the browser?

I use chrome browser and tried to add png/jpg files, but nothing happend - on_dropped_file doesn't called

regads, max

**UPD**: I lied. After drop image from browser, the program recognizes the object as "text/plain" with url in Gtk::SelectionData.

Comment: What browser(s)? What image type(s)? Have you tried dragging them over, and what happens?

Comment: @underscore_d chrome and png or jpg. I tried and nothing happend.  on_dropped_file doesn't called